# Additional tab separated column while Compressing Decompressing Hdfs File through Mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am compressing  a text file on Hdfs in Bzip2 format using

```
FileOutputFormat.setCompressOutput(jobConf, true);  
FileOutputFormat.setOutputCompressorClass(jobConf,BZip2Codec.class);
```

and decompressing it using mapreduce

```
TextInputFormat.setInputPaths(jobConf,"//Bizip file Path");     
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(jobConf, new Path(outputFilePath));
```

but the output contain additional tab    separated column

```
Input - 1,XYZ
        2,ABC
Output- 0 -> 1,XYZ
        11-> 2,ABC
```

Although, while using unix command `bzip2 -k /filename.txt`
and b`unzip2 /filename.bz2` no additional data is getting added.

Comment: And what is the question exactly?

Comment: Why there is additional column while using mapreduce and how to remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0,11` are line offset. f you don't need that set your output key as `NullWritable` in BZip2Codec.class.

Comment: Thanks, adding a mapper to set output key NullWritable solves my problem.

Comment: @user5462236 I am glad it worked. If it resolves your problem please accept the answer.